Given final block not properly padded... again
I have a very strange issue when generating the signed app.
I have been using the same jks file for several years.
All of a sudden I got the message in the title. I copy/paste passwords, so this cannot be the problem.
With exactly the same jks file on my other machine everything works just fine.
The only difference that I can see is that the error is on AS 2023.1.1 and for AS 2022.2.1 Patch 2 it works fine.
Any ideas?
Copied jks file, entered password manually (as some people suggested), moved jks file in a different location.

Are you sure the JKS file was not overwritten or replaced? Restore it from an older backup. BTW are you sure the file ending is correct? If it would be a PKCS#12 thus p12 file this could be caused by the default encryption algo change Java performed some versions ago.

The files on both machines have the same names and timestamps. How do you control the encryption algorithm?

I would load it into KeyStoreExplorer. If the password is accepted it shows you the actual store type (e.g. JKS or PKCS#12 in the bottom status line). If it is a JKS then crypto is not the problem as this is specific to PKCS#12.

KeyStoreExplorer opens the file just fine. It shows RSA algorithm for key0. The file type is PKCS #12. I still have no clue what to do to make it work.

The easiest way would be to use KeyStoreExplorer and save it as real JKS keystore (Use Tools -> Change KeyStore Type -> JKS). Then you wouldn't have to care about the PKCS#12 crypto problems which Java Runtime supports the AES encryption scheme on which only supports the old 3DES.
